# git - add tag but exclude merged commits

Tags: git, bitbucket-server, git-tag

Using git repos, git bash shell for interaction; using BitBucket for Code Reviews and Merging, creating Branches, etc.

We'd like to create a Service Pack 'Tag', but there are Commits that have been Merged we don't want included in the Service Pack (one Commit/Merge we want to completely remove). We have considered using 'git revert' to move the undesired Commits to the top, but feel that will not get us the desired effect. We have also considered a 'git reset', but unclear if that will work.

The screenshot shows what we want: remove 'commit-a' (has broken code), and want the SP Tag to include 'commit-b' and 'commit-f' but not the others.  Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

[commit image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8aJu.png)

Answer (score 0):

After more discussion internally, it was decided that a new Branch will be created at the Commit prior to "commit-a", and then cherry-pick Commits "-b" and "-f".